# The dual coxeter number is the inverse of the norm of the highest root: looking for a simple proof

Tags: reference-request, lie-algebras

Does anybody know a simple generic proof (or a reference for it) for the following formula?:

If $\theta=\sum a_i\alpha_i$ is the highest root of a simple complex lie algebra with $\Delta=\{\alpha_1, \cdots,\alpha_n\}$ as simple roots system, we denote $\theta^{\vee}=\sum c_i\alpha_i^{\vee}$ the corresponding coroot.

The dual Coxeter number is then defined as $h^{\vee}=1+\sum c_i$, and we have the formula for which I am looking for a proof
$$h^{\vee}=\frac1{\kappa^*(\theta, \theta)}$$
where $\kappa^*$ is the scalar product on the dual of the Cartan subalgebra of the Lie algebra coming from the Killing form.

Comment: See [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiNy8WOu4HrAhWE2aQKHRGICoQ4ChAWMAl6BAgJEAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Frefubium.fu-berlin.de%2Fbitstream%2Fhandle%2Ffub188%2F1275%2F3_chapter2.pdf%3Fsequence%3D4%26isAllowed%3Dy&usg=AOvVaw0Ywa4ckpkTkzM4YxBVQlbH), from $(2.8)$ to $(2.17)$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde thank you for the interesting reference, but unfortunately it is not really a proof since the author defines the killing form by using precisely the relation I want to prove (and it is the first time I see the Killing form defines with such a factor) so there is nothing to prove here. If we use the usual definition of the Killing form, how can we get the formula ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde well, you are clearly not wrong. What you mean is that I can check using the classification of all simple complex finite Lie algebras that the formula works well. I agree 100% but I was looking for a more generic proof, not by checking it works on a case by case basis. A proof like the one for the Freudenthal strange formula (which can also be checked by hand) ...

Comment: How do you define $\kappa(\theta,\theta)$ then?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Using the generic definition of the Killing form: $\kappa(\theta, \theta)=\text{Tr}(\text{ad}(\theta)\text{ad}(\theta))$

Comment: $\theta$ is not an element of the Lie algebra.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Oupss... once again you are right. I mean $\kappa(\theta^*, \theta^*)$ where $\theta^*$ is the element of the Cartan algebra $H$ of the algebra that corresponds to $\theta$ after we transport it using the non-degeneracy of the Killing form on $H^*$. I will edit my question to make it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at a seminal paper of Dynkin, I found the following proof that I include here with simplified notations, with the algebra of rank $r$:

We use a Cartan-Weyl basis $((H_i), (E_\alpha))$ where $1\leq i\leq r$, $(H_i)$ an orthonormal basis for the Killing form of the Cartan subalgebra, and $(E_\alpha)$ the root vectors belonging to the root spaces of the algebra, with $\alpha\in\Phi$, the set of all roots, and normalize such that $\kappa(E_\alpha, E_{-\alpha})=1$.

The Casimir operator is
$$C=\sum_i H^2_i+\sum_{\alpha\in\Phi^+}(E_\alpha E_{-\alpha}+E_{-\alpha} E_{\alpha})$$

By checking its trace, it is easy to see that it is the identity on the adjoint representation of the algebra.

If $\theta$ is the highest root, and $E_\theta$ a non zero vector of its root space, which is a highest weight vector for the adjoint representation, we have $\alpha\in\Phi^+$ $\text{ad}(E_\alpha)(E_\theta)=0$, therefore
$$\text{ad}(C)(E_\theta)=\kappa(E_\theta, E_\theta)E_\theta+\sum_{\alpha\in\Phi^+}\kappa(E_\theta, E_\alpha)E_\theta=(\kappa^*(\theta, \theta)+2\kappa^*(\theta, \rho))E_\theta$$
where $\rho$ is the half-sum of all the positive roots.

We get immediately
$$1=\kappa^*(\theta, \theta)h^{\vee}$$